# Ui Addon shows some error when I run it on G1ANT RPA Studio

Tags: g1ant

I have used the Ui addon and it shows this error, please have look and see what I should do make it correct. This link has error that has occurred when I executed some program using the Ui addon.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ8EH.png

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem that you are facing initially. To solve this program, run G1ANT studio as administrator, it worked for me. Try it!